# elasticsearch index transactions

Tags: search-engine, elasticsearch

I am exploring elasticsearch and comparing it with our current search solution. The use case I have is, , everytime I build index, I have to drop the current index and create the new one with the same name. So that all the old docs are dropped with the old index and the new index will have the fresh data. The indexing process takes couple of minutes to finish.

My question is what happens to the search requests coming in during this time. Does elastic search uses transaction and only commit all changes (dropping the index and new index with the new documents) in a transaction?

What happens if I deleted the index, and an error occurs during the middle of the indexing?
If there are no transactions, is there any workaround to this situation?

Answer (score 6):

Elasticsearch doesn't support transactions. When you delete an index, you delete an index. Until you create a new index users will be getting IndexMissingException exceptions. Once the new index is created they will see only records that were indexed and refreshed (by default refresh occurs every second).

One way to hide this from users is by using [aliases](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-aliases/). You can create an alias that will point to an index. When you need to reindex your data, you can create a new index, index new data there, switch the alias to the new index and delete the old index.

Comment: Aliases sounds a perfect fit for my case. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is there a java api to get the actual index name associated with given alias? I would need to know the name of the actual index associated with the alias in order to drop it later on.

Comment: Take a look at how it's implemented in [RestGetIndices](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/admin/indices/alias/RestGetIndicesAliasesAction.java#L66)